# Get document identifier, Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the ID of my fields. But when I click on the elements of my listview, it shows me identifiers that does not exist in the database and changes to each click.

Database:
 [image: Database]

Display:

[image: Display]
[image]

Code:
[image: Code]

How can I get the id of the address selected in the listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, where is Geneva put what you want.

Inside onClick PositiveButton:

```
    db.collection("Adresse").whereEqualTo("Adresse", "Geneva").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e);
                return;
            }

            for (DocumentChange dc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                String docid = dc.getDocument().getId();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), docid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```